# Скрыть маркер в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста как скрыть маркер на карте Google Maps и на его позиции отобразить инфо-окно? Как скрыть маркер нашёл, но инфо-окно отображается так, как будто там есть маркер, а надо чтобы именно на той же самой позиции было инфо-окно, что и у маркера. Возможно ли это?

Comment: повесьте на маркер клик, в обработчике которого снимите с маркера координаты, убейте маркер и создайте инфоокно с координатами маркера способом, который ниже вам правильно поведал @Павел Азанов

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#InfoWindow) есть такая фраза:

> An InfoWindow can be placed on a map at a particular position or above a marker, depending on what is specified in the options.

То есть привязка к маркеру необязательна. Примерный код для создания окна с позиционированием просто задавая координаты:

```
var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWnd.setContent('Это окно без маркера');
infoWnd.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523));
infoWnd.open(map);
```